# How to change the cursor when over TLF text?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, tlf

With any of the editable text fields such as RichEditableText, TextArea and any TextFlow containers the cursor is always the familiar text entry pipe character with serifs thing. Whatever.

I need to be able to change that to a hand cursor as it moves over an inline graphic image and then revert back to text entry cursor on mouse out.

I've been looking at the CursorManager class but have had no luck yet.

**UPDATE:**
I found a class FlowElementMouseEventManager that manages the cursor as it moves over a text flow container. It's not clear how to change the cursor to a hand cursor yet but the LinkElement will change to a hand cursor when the mouse is over it and the CTRL is held down.

Answer (score 0):

Set `buttonmode = true` for that inline graphic image and you are good to go

Comment: I tried that and unfortunately it doesn't work. One of my other questions has example code you can try I can't post in here atm